# jQuery UI Dialog—Close Button Not Working

Tags: jquery

I'm having some trouble getting the close button on my dialog box to work. I followed an example I found, but mine won't close. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $('#message').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        bgiframe: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Okay': function() {
                document.location = 
                    'http://www.google.com';
                    },
            'Cancel': function() {
            ('#message').dialog('close');
        }
        }
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#message').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFFWq/3/)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the $. It is

```
$('#message').dialog('close');
```

I recommend using a developer tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It will display a detailed error message in the console.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
('#message').dialog('close');
```

use :

```
$(this).dialog('close')
```

Comment: I've changed it to this, but it still doesn't seem to work. I've added a jsFiddle to my original post.

Comment: you're right! I don't know why... but if you remove this lines : 
$('button').click(function() {
        $('#message').dialog('open');
and make the dialog autoOpen : true... then the close button work! Maybe there is something in the button script that make js not valid...

Comment: Thanks for checking into this again but it was a rather careless mistake on my part. I didn't assign my button an id, so every time I clicked the "cancel" button it would try to open the dialog box again!

Answer (score 2):

It's the line:

'Cancel': function() {
            ('#message').dialog('close');
        }

Change it to:

'Cancel': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }

Answer (score 1):

Since my click event is referring to a general button, hitting the cancel button essentially opened the dialog again. I gave the button an id and referenced that.